# Blacklist some method calls with Scala Compiler plugin

Tags: scala, compiler-construction

I wanted to create a scala compiler plugin that would prevents the call of some functions. For example System.exit.
The idea behind the scene is to let people write Scala scripts that would be interpreted on the fly. But I want to ensure that some dangerous actions are prohibited - the way it is done can definitely be discussed.

I started with the example in http://www.scala-lang.org/node/140 and started to replace the Apply section.
Doing some pattern matching I was able to extract a ClassSymbol for the right part of the compilation unit.
Then I wanted to do something like in the example that would be like:

```
classSymbol.tpe =:= global.typeOf[System]
```

unfortunately they don't match I get System.type on one side and System on the other.

Of course I could compare String values but I think that there is perhaps a nicer way to achieve this.
Has anyone any advice ?

Just in case a larger part of the code:

```
  def apply(unit: global.CompilationUnit) {

    for (global.Apply(fun, _) <- unit.body) {
      fun.symbol match {
        case method: global.MethodSymbol =>
          val classSymbol = method.owner
          println(classSymbol.fullName)
          println(classSymbol.tpe =:= global.typeOf[System])
        case _ => ()
      }
    }
```

Comment: One suggestion is to look for usage of `=:=` in the scalac's source code. Oh, and its implementation. Provide feedback if you do these things.

Comment: Speculation: if System is in compilers classpath, it maybe loaded by a different classloader, the one used to compile. This would render them  different types in the JVM point of view.

Comment: Why not just use the JVM's SecurityManager facility?

Comment: I could use JVM Security Manager (cf what I said in my post that the way it is done can be challenged).In fact the idea is that someone can write and compile script locally before submitting the code (I mean it will be recompiled/evaluated).I would like to be able to notify the user before she submits the script. Therefore if I can warn her as soon as possible and avoid useless steps. It is also an opportunity to learn a bit deeper how the Scala type system works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps,

```
val jls = global.findMemberFromRoot(TermName("java.lang.System"))
```

Comment: Are you sure "java.lang.System" is one term name?

Comment: @pedrofurla How about that? Works for me.

Comment: Thanks, this answer works for me. Don't know if this is the best way to do but it solved my problem. It helped me also to "discover" some nice docs on scala-lang website related to this topic: http://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/reflection/overview.html (have a look around, there are interesting pages). Thanks again for the suggestion

Comment: @user2595797  Of course it's the best way to do it. Definitions already knows java.lang, so you could `global.definitions.JavaLangPackageClass.typeSignature.member(TermName("System"))` but that looks like extra typing (on the keyboard) to me.

Comment: I went through the link I shared above and you're right!- sorry - By the way do you knowwhat is the gap between "Global" package used in plugins and universes used in reflection ?

Comment: @user2595797 that makes it ok.  Sometimes I'm actually right.  I do know that scaladoc for the whole reflection api (and compiler-side integration) is painful to search, but Eugene answers everyone's questions, and the more I know about it, the more I appreciate what they have accomplished so far.

Comment: @user2595797 Sometimes (e.g. from macros) you have to downcast to get the functionality you need.  They erred on the side of, be conservative, you can always add api but taking it away is harder.

Comment: I agree, I think implementation is great but hard to grasp because doc is hard to find but when you find it, things start to be clearer